# PHP DOMDocument adding child xml feed

Tags: php, domdocument

If want xml to do this:

```
    <itunes:owner>
        <itunes:name>Name</itunes:name>
        <itunes:email>email</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>
```

This code does not work. the `name` and `email` is not between `owner` tags.

instead it is doing this:

```
    <itunes:owner> </itunes:owner>
    <itunes:name>Name</itunes:name>
    <itunes:email>email</itunes:email>
```

This PHP code does not work. the `name` and `email` is not between `owner` tags.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
 ...
    $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:owner', 'ame'));
    $chanow = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:name', 'Name'));
    $chanow = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:email', 'email'));
```

So how do I add the child element?

Sorry this is my first experience with `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to append a Child to the wrong parent.

```
$chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:owner', 'ame'));
```

Try this:

```
$xml->formatOutput = true; //better readability

$chan = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:owner'));
$chanow = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:name', 'Name'));
$chanow = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:email', 'email'));

echo $xml->saveXML(); //displaying the output
```

This should produce the following output:

```
<itunes:owner>
  <itunes:name>Name</itunes:name>
  <itunes:email>email</itunes:email>
</itunes:owner>
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/48144)

Comment: Thank You! In my case i needed to change to:$chan = $chan-> instead of $chan = $xml ...  because i wanted it to sub out of the channel tag. But you did not have the context. Very helpful!

Comment: @user2533570: Glad to have been of help! :)